# Crash when setting a new screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my almost finished game I want to set a new screen on game over. I got my game over method:

```
    private void gameOver(Label score) {
    for (Body body : worldBodies) {
        world.destroyBody(body);
        dispose();
        ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameOver());
    }
}
```

Whenever the method gets called the screen freezes for a second and the game crashes with this statement:

```
09-02 22:04:34.036      391-425/com.joelbrun.jetskirider.android A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 425 (GLThread 29501)
```

Comment: More information is needed to pin-point what's going wrong here, for example;
Do you have any joints between bodies that are being destroyed?
What does the `dispose` method do?
Do you hit any method that tries to use the destroyed bodies after this call?

Comment: Please show the dispose(); method.

Answer (score 3):

Move this after the for loop:

```
dispose();
((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameOver());
```

You create/set a new GameOver Screen each iteration, that causes probably the freeze and problems.